# Can I send a postcode direct to google maps in the url line and return local hotels

Tags: html, google-maps

Hi I have a form on my web page that includes a postcode. I want to open a new window and display google maps with the data from my postcode form and to reference hotels in the area  Ideally something like

www.maps.google.co.uk%postcode=pr87uu&hotels

Is this something I can do easily ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks Mick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost had it...

here is an example:

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=ec3m+5ad+hotel
```